# ?attr/selectableItemBackground with state_selected

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use `?attr/selectableItemBackground` to set clicks, focus, selection, activation etc. to a list item view in my `RecyclerView`. After some digging I found out that `selectableItemBackground`  doesn't provide selection states. Is there another theme attribute I can use(with ripples and all for L)?